# Prove that there exists $\xi \in (-1,1)$ such that $f'''(\xi)=3.$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

#### Problem

Assume that $f(x)$ has the $3$-order continuous derivative over $[-1,1]$, and $f(-1)=0,f(1)=1,f'(0)=0$. Prove that there exists $\xi \in (-1,1)$ such that $f'''(\xi)=3.$

#### Proof

According to Taylor's formula of $f(x)$ expanding at $x=0$
$$f(x)=f(0)+\frac{x^2f''(0)}{2}+\frac{x^3f'''(\xi)}{6},~~~0\lessgtr \xi \lessgtr x,$$
we obtain
$$0=f(-1)=f(0)+\frac{f''(0)}{2}-\frac{f'''(\xi_1)}{6},~~~-1<\xi_1<0,$$
$$1=f(1)=f(0)+\frac{f''(0)}{2}+\frac{f'''(\xi_2)}{6},~~~0<\xi_2<1.$$
By substraction, we have
$$f'''(\xi_1)+f'''(\xi_2)=6,$$
which implies, $f'''(\xi_1),f'''(\xi_2)$ are both equal to $3$，or，one of them is greater than $3$ and the other less than $3$. For the former case,the conclusion holds trivially；as for the latter one, according to the continuity of $f'''(x)$, applying the intermediate value theorem, there exists $\xi_3 \in (\xi_1,\xi_2)\subset (-1,1)$ such that$f'''(\xi_3)=3$，the conclusion holds as well.

#### Comment

But I suggest that, we only need the existence of $f'''(x)$, and the continuity of it is not necessary. That's because, according to Darboux's theorem, the derivative function itself has the intermediate value property.

Comment: I agree with your comment. But remember that in the real world, some times your givens are stronger than what's strictly necessary to get the desired result. Some times that's even  an actual hindrance for progress (because you miss that you can discard information). Exercises ought to exercise that from time to time in my opinion.

Comment: The continuity assumption is needed for using the Taylor's theorem in that particular form.

Comment: @Test123 no,you're wrong!